# Modify content pdf PrintDocumentAdapter web view

Tags: android, pdf, webview

i am using PrintDocumentAdapter for generate a pdf from  web view content:

```
PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

        PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter;
        // Get a print adapter instance
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            try {
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_hhmmss", Locale.US);
                String hour = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter(hour + "_" + person.getDocument().getDocumentId());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter("Documento");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter();
        }

 String jobName = this.getString(R.string.app_name) + "Document";
        printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter,
                new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
```

And this code works fine for me, but i have a questions:

¿Is it possible to add a header to this pdf generated by the PrintDocumentAdapter ? 
I want generate a pdf with the content of the web view but add to the 
content of pdf an header:

By example structure final pdf:

[HEADER]Generated by my app

[CONTENT]Content of pdf original

Comment: There is nothing built in for this. Either put the header in the HTML in the `WebView` or find a PDF library that lets you add this header.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but,¿ Is this possible, for example I load facebook.com in the web view, can I add a header to the web view?

Comment: That would be difficult, unless you know the exact structure of the Web page that you are loading.

Comment: Then with the native android library, ¿is there another way to capture web view content in a pdf, not screenshoot?

Comment: No, there is nothing else in Android set up to convert a Web page into PDF form.

Comment: @DayronCediel What you did to achieve the header in pdf?
Please share